# What is Yoga - Philosophy or a form of physical exercise?

Tags: yoga

**1.** I am greatly confused as to what is Yoga ?  - Is it a form of physical exercise with certain poses ?
Or Is it some philosophy like Sankhya ?

Also why is Yoga prefixed in words like "Karma Yoga" ,"Bhakti Yoga" etc.

Also

**2.** Why is Krishna called Yogeshwar ( God of Yoga) ?

Comment: If you see the etymology of the word yoga, it is derived from word yuj to join/unite.It is that which leads to the harmony of individual consciousness with universal consciousness.BG shows the means and the destination to unite with the divine thru nishkama karma (KarmaYog) and nishkama bhakti(BhaktiYog). Patanjali yoga sutras centres on (yoga as) chitta vritti nirodha, to ascend to the state of samadhi.SankyaDarsana has influence on yogaDarsana, as they are related theoretically to a major extent.As Shri Krishna is the lord(Ishwar) of yogis, whom yogis seek, Lord is Yogeshwar

Comment: Hatha yoga (physical) is prerequisite for Raja yoga

Comment: The use of the word Yoga in reference to Hatha Yoga poses and practices should not be conflated with the use of the word Yoga  as it is generally used with Vedanta. Hatha Yoga are bodily exercises and will make the mind more attached (joined, in union) to the body. The aim of Yoga in the Vedantic sense (karma, raja, jnana) is union with God, to make the mind less attached to the body and attached to God. The aims and attainments are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is Yoga?** Rśi Patañjali started his Sutras by saying "And now Yoga". There is an ocean of meaning hidden deep in this one statement. So let me quote from one of the oldest translations of Yoga by I.K.Taimni as to what is Yoga

> The word Yoa in Smskrta has a very large number of meanings. It is derived from the root *Yuj* which means 'to join' or 'unite' and the idea of joining runs through all the meanings. **What are the two things which are sought to be joined by the practice of Yoga?** According to the highest conceptions of Hindu Philosophy of which the Science of Yoga is an integral part, the human Soul or the Jīvātmā is a facet or partial expression of the Over-Soul or Paramātmā, the Divine Reality which is the source of the Substratum of the manifested Universe. Although in essence the two are the same and are indivisible, still, the Jīvātmā has become subjectively separate from Paramātmā and is destined, after going through an evolutionary cycle in the manifested Universe, to become unified with Him again in consciousness. This state of unification of the two in consciousness as well as the mental process and discipline through which this union is attained are both called Yoga.

**Is it some philosophy like Sankhya?** Again quote from I.K.Taimni

> These sutras bearing upon Isvara have given rise to a controversy among scholars because Sāṃkhya is supposed to be an atheistic doctrine and Yoga is supposed to be an atheistic doctrine and Yoga is supposed to be based on Sāṃkhya. The relation between Sāṃkhya and Yoga has not really been definitely settled through the philosophy of Yoga is bound up so closely with that of Sāṃkhya that the Yoga system is sometimes referred ta as himself over these academic questions of philosophy. Yoga is a theoretical basis that may or may not in reality correspond exactly with the facts which form the real basis of the science. The system of Yoga outlined by Patañjali is essentially a scientific system of philosophy for its theoretical basis which is most scientific in its outlook and comprehensive in its treatment. The choice of Sāṃkhyafor this purpose was therefore quite natural. But this does not mean necessarily that Yoga is based on Sāṃkhya or follows that system in toto. This very fact that it differs from Sāṃkhya on the most fundamental question of Isvara and has suggested an independent method of attaining Samadhi through Isvara-Pranidhana shows that this apparent similarity of the two systems should not be taken too seriously. The fact that Sāṃkhya while dealing with theoretical questions at great length is almost silent with regard to the practical methods of obtaining release from the bondage of Avidya is also of great significance.

**Is it a form of physical exercise?** Rśi Patañjali's Yoga sutras are called Astanga Yoga, meaning 8-limbs of Yoga. The first 5 limbs create a conducive environment for the last 3 limbs. These last 3 are meditative states. Among the first 5, Āsana (posture) is given the highest significance these days in the form of physical exercise, however, the root for these exercises lies with the Haṭha-Yoga. Again, let's

> Many people who do not know anything about Yoga confuse it with these physical exercises. It is, however, necessary even for the student of Yogic philosophy to understand clearly the place and purpose of Āsana (posture) in Raja-Yoga (another dimension of yoga dealing with Will), for in Haṭha-Yoga and certain systems of physical culture their purpose is very different. Haṭha-Yoga the subject of Āsanas is treated at great length and there are at least 84 Āsanas that are described in detail. very specific and sometimes exaggerated results being attributed to many of them. There is no doubt that many of these Āsanas, by affecting the endocrine glands and Pranic currents, tend to bring about a very marked change in the body and if practiced correctly and for a sufficiently long time promote health in a remarkable manner. Haṭha-Yoga is based on the principle that changes in consciousness can be brought about by setting in motion currents of certain kinds of subtler forces (Prana, Kundalini) in the physical body.

**Why is Yoga fixed in words like "Karma Yoga","Bhakti Yoga" etc?** There are various dimensions to Yoga as the root word of Yoga means "union". We have seen clearly how Rśi Patañjali cumulated the entire essence of yoga into his formulas called Sutras. Bhagavad Gita (an integral part of Mahabharatam) is an expo on both Sāṃkhya and various dimensions of Yoga. The Yoga (union) through Action in line with Dharma is called Karma Yoga, the one done by utmost surrender is called Bhakti Yoga.

**Why is Krishna called Yogeshwar ( God of Yoga)?** Rśi Patañjali doesn't address Divinity with names but rather addresses Consciousness as Ishvara and Ishvara being Vishesha Purusha (Special Purusha). As per Mahabharatam Drona Parva 203 (core Jaya section) says, Sankara is:

> “He (Sankara) is Yoga and the Abode/Lord of Yoga”

So, Rudra/Samkara became Adi Yogi, the first yogi who is one with creation. Vedas say that as Rudra and Some  who brought forth the Seven Sages (saptarśi) as the Seven Gems. [RV6.74.1]. He had no name and came from the North Mountains (Mūjavant), and dwelled in mountains, they called him Girisha. As he was the foremost, they placed him on Dakshina and so called him Dakshina Murthi [SU4.21]. Since he married the daughter of those mountains, as Kenopanishad says “Uma daughter of Himavat” they called him Umapathi [TA10.22.40.22]. All beings (bhootas) flocked around him, including pious, nefarious, and animals, especially snakes as they have unique chemistry with those in a meditative state, so they called him Paśūpati/Satpati/Bhootapati [TS4.5.2, RV2.33.12, AV11.2.1] so as an overlord of all beings they called him **Isha**. He was independent and sovereign they called Svatantra, Svadhanva and Svatava [RV1.166.2] (Sva = sovereign).
Since he was the supreme overload/authority they called him Isha. So together he was titled Isha + Sva = Ishvar.
In him they saw Mahat = the great principle, so they called him Maha + Isha + Svara = Mahesvara. In him they saw Vishvam, they called him Vishveswara. In him they saw everything (Sarva) so they called him Sarveshwara CKA2.100. They saw highest Divinity in him so they called him Mahadeva [SB6.3].
They saw his janan:netra on his forehead so they called him Triambaka & Virupaksha.
When he consumed the anti-creation element in his throat, they called him Nilakanta.
He was fair to both devas and asuras so they called him Harikesha.
He wore no clothes nor decorations so they called Digambara. He removed the darkness of Avidya so he was Andhashaspati. No one knows who he is, or where he came from, they saw nothing but auspiciousness so they called Shiva. He removed their sufferings and gave them salvation so they called him Samkara [TS4.5.8].

Sri Krishana who is Nārāyaṇa (a complete manifestation of Śrī Mahā Viṣṇu) orated the essence of Yoga and Sāṃkhya in 18 chapters totaling 700 verses covering various dimensions of Yoga. Hence is popularly called Yogeshwara. But the most accurate term is **Gitacharya** and he Himself is a Rudra [Dhrona parve -Narayana moksha parva]. As he put into practice all his Yogic oration. Hence is a complete personification of the Divine.

Sources: Book-Science of Yoga. by I. K. Taimni, Link-[Lord of Yoga](https://wordpress.com/view/namahshivaya.net)